# Find unknown x coordinate from log graph

Tags: logarithms

[image]

I am not sure where to start on this question.

I am not sure how to fit the coordinates into the equation $y=\log_3(x-4)$

Comment: (q,2) is point on the graph so setting x to q and y to 2 you get $2 = \log_3 (q-4) $.  Solve for q.  Which you do by rising three to each side to get $3^2 = x+4$.  That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just $3^y=x-4$ so as $q,2$ lies on it we have $9=q-4$ thus $q=13$

Comment: Is the coordinate (5, 0) irrelevant in this case?

Comment: Ya can be said like that